# Create table in migration with ENGINE clause fails

Tags: php, mysql, yii, migration

I am trying to do a migration using Yii and create new table in `up()` method. 
It works fine as long as I don't add the `ENGINE=InnoDB` clause. In that case - it gives me an error `near ENGINE`.

```
public function up()
{
    $this->createTable('tbl_project', array(
        'id' => 'pk',
        'name' => 'string NOT NULL',
        'description' => 'text NOT NULL',
        'create_time' => 'datetime DEFAULT NULL',
        'create_user_id' => 'int(11) DEFAULT NULL',
        'update_time' => 'datetime DEFAULT NULL',
        'update_user_id' => 'int(11) DEFAULT NULL',
    ), 'ENGINE=InnoDB');
}
```

My version of Yii is 1.1.12. PHP 5.4.3, MySQL 5.5.24.

Is that some Yii bug?

EDIT (yii bug description):

```
*** applying m130208_133533_create_table_project
> create table tbl_project ...exception 'CDbException' with message 'CDbComm
and failed to execute the SQL statement: CDbCommand failed to prepare the SQL st
atement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "engine": syntax error. The SQL
statement executed was: CREATE TABLE 'tbl_project' (
    "id" integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    "name" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "description" text NOT NULL,
    "create_time" datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    "create_user_id" int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    "update_time" datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    "update_user_id" int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) engine = InnoDB' in C:\wamp\yii\framework\db\CDbCommand.php:357
```

Comment: Not positive this will work, but try changing changing " 'ENGINE=InnoDB' " to " Type='InnoDB' ". If that doesn't work you can try changing it to " ENGINE='InnoDB' "

Comment: Nope. Tried `Type` but not working. Space in front of it also doesn't work (in SQL you can also put ENGINE right after `)` sign).

Comment: sorry, have you solved this issue ?

Comment: Actually I haven't. Meanwhile version of Yii slightly moved up so it may work already. Frankly I don't know. Have you tried methods from this thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using "protected\yiic\migrate", being a console command, uses protected\config\console.php, so its "db" component should be configured properly (as protected\config\main.php was configured). If you get the InnoDB error, chances are you are still configured for SQLite.

Comment: It's customary to provide example code to your answers to increase it's understandability. Also, note that the question to which you are giving a answer is more than a year old.

Comment: @HristoValkanov - the answer is actually good (I resolved it quite a while ago but forgot to post the answer here). This answer does not need the code as it is more which-file than code-error problem.

Comment: I never said his answer was bad ;)
All I said was that it looks incomplete. He could have showed a example code like: "Look for a line that looks something like XXX, and check if it ends with YYYY." or something like that. I comented since I saw many times someone providing the correct answer, which lacks examples, and OP waits for 30 min+ for someone to rephrase the already given answer. And guess who's answer was accepted...
So it was just a friendly advice ;)

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and it was solved by checking  that the configuration of the database in console.php & main.php are the same

```
i.e 'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databasename',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'ur password',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),
```

and comment the sqlite lines in both files

Comment: No, that's not the point unfortunately. Easy to check - I made tables through MySQL console - I can easily connect to it and make model/CRUD for example. It's about the `ENGINE` clause. Weird but I guess you just have to do it through the MySQL console.

Comment: The error doesnt provide any clue on the actual reason.However this is the fix.

Comment: @Joe hi there, I met the same problem as you today, and found this is the perfect solution. Let me explain why. The sql syntax error of "CREATE TABLE 'tbl_project' (
    "id" integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    "name" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "description" text NOT NULL,"

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$this->createTable('tbl_project', array(
        'id' => 'pk',
        'name' => 'string NOT NULL',
        'description' => 'text NOT NULL',
        'create_time' => 'datetime DEFAULT NULL',
        'create_user_id' => 'int(11) DEFAULT NULL',
        'update_time' => 'datetime DEFAULT NULL',
        'update_user_id' => 'int(11) DEFAULT NULL',
    ), 
    'engine = InnoDB'
);
```

If it doesn't work then show us the MySql error

Comment: Not sure but did you change only `ENGINE` to `engine`? I added MySQL error to my question for you. Thx.

Comment: Its an example of a working migration that I have, I just used your values and left the rest intact just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to include on .env file:

`DB_ENGINE=InnoDB`